# How do we change the comma separated numbers in each cell to single number in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with columns (M1 and M2...M20) having responses like:

```
ID  M1     M2
1   4,7     5,6
2   4,7     6,5
3   5,4     4,6
```

```
> class(dataframe$M1)
[1] "character"
```

I want to change the response options from comma-separated numbers to a single number. So it should look like this, where the correct response for M1 column (4,7 ) is replaced by 1, else 0 and similarly for M2 to M20.

```
ID  M1     M2
1   1     1
2   1     1
3   0     0
```

And this I want this for the entire dataset which has ID as rows and 20 columns as responses. While other columns having their unique values to be replaced with 1 and 0. I would like to have a solution for a single column that can be modified and replicated.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Shoudn't we need to know what are the correct responses for each column? For column `M2` it seems to be either `5,6` or `6,5`.

Comment: How do we know what is the correct response

Answer (score 1):

```
dataframe$M1<-as.numeric(dataframe$M1=="4,7")
```

This will give you a column of 1's and 0's.

If you have a list of all the "right answers" for each column -- for example:

```
answers<-list("4,7",c("5,6","6,5"))
```

you can loop through them:

```
for (i in 1:length(answers)) {
   dataframe[,i+1]<-as.numeric(dataframe[,i+1] %in% answers[[i]])
 }

dataframe
  ID M1 M2
1  1  1  1
2  2  1  1
3  3  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume `M` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end and also we have the `correct` list whose ith component is a vector of values of those answers to the ith question which are correct.  If there are multiple correct answers then the ith component of `correct` is a vector of them.  Then we can use the following `mapply`

```
Recode <- function(m, cor) m %in% cor
replace(M, -1, + mapply(Recode, M[-1], correct))
```

giving:

```
  ID M1 M2
1  1  1  1
2  2  1  1
3  3  0  0
```

No packages are used.

### Note

The inputs in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- 
"ID  M1     M2
1   4,7     5,6
2   4,7     6,5
3   5,4     4,6"
M <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)

# correct[[i]] is a character vector of the correct answers for question i
correct <- list("4,7", c("5,6", "6,5"))
```

Comment: Hi, can you give a play by play explanation of that replace call? I'm having difficulty figuring it out.

Comment: mapply applies the function to the ith column of M[-1] together with the ith component of correct for each i giving an nrow(M) by ncol(M)-1 matrix and then replaces the columns of M, except the first, with that.  You can run the parts of it separately to see the intermediate results.   For example, this checks the M2 against the second correct vector: `+Recode(M[-1][[2]], correct[[2]])`